# Check if part of url regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have nodes in a navigation tree. I want to select all the nodes that are part of the url so I can highlight them. I had it working but forgot an edge case where the last part of the url starts with the same string.

In this case if somebody is at the url `/products/foobar-super` I want it to select `/products` and `/products/foobar-super` but not `/products/foobar`.

```
describe('part of url', function () {

  it('matches /products and /products/foobar-super', function () {

    var current = '/producten/foobar-super';

    var nodes = [
      '/products',
      '/products/foobar',
      '/products/foobar-super',
    ];

    var result = [];

    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
      if (new RegExp(node + '.*').test(current)) {
        result.push(node);
      }
    });

    result.should.eql([
      '/products',
      '/products/foobar-super',
    ]);

  });

});
```

Jsfiddle with the test: http://jsfiddle.net/RKDga/2/

Not sure if it is possible with a regex the other solution I guess is to split the node and the current url on `/` compare those.

Comment: Yes! The second one, split the url on / and check. It's _very_ simple, you'll be able to go back to it in a month and understand exactly what it does. I suggest you write this code yourself and answer this question yourself, I suspect you'll be able to do so just fine.

Comment: Just wrote it guess I was stuck thinking to solve this with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test will pass if

```
new RegExp(node + '.*')
```

is changed to

```
new RegExp(node + '(/|$)')
```

It prevents a match unless `node` is followed by `/` or the end of the string.

Comment: Since I was asking for a regex in my question I'll accept your answer. It's so simple I am actually a little embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help you  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RKDga/4/)

```
    /*globals mocha: true, describe: true, it: true, beforeEach:true */
(function() {
    function assert(expr, msg) {
        if (!expr) throw new Error(msg || 'failed');
    }

    mocha.setup({
        ui: "bdd",
        ignoreLeaks: true
    });

    describe('part of url', function () {

      it('matches /products and /products/foobar-super', function () {

        var current = '/products/foobar-super';

        var nodes = [
          '/products',
          '/products/foobar',
          '/products/foobar-super',
        ];

        var result = [];
         ;
    var urllist =  current.split("/");
   var temp; 
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
       temp = "";
      for(var i=1;i<urllist.length; i++){
            temp += "/"+ urllist[i];
          if(node == temp){
             result.push(node );
          }
      }
    });

 console.log(result);          

        assert(result[0] === '/products', 'first item should be /products');
        assert(result[1] === '/products/foobar-super', 'second item should be /products/foobar-super');


      });

    });


mocha.run();
}());
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: @Juhana I added jsfiddle link.

Comment: That's cool, but would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an other solution without a regex:

```
describe('part of url', function () {

  it('matches /products and /products/foobar-super', function () {

    var current = '/products/foobar-super';

    var nodes = [
      '/products',
      '/products/foobar',
      '/products/foobar-super',
    ];

    var result = [];

    nodes.forEach(function (node) {

      var node_parts = node.split('/');
      var current_parts = current.split('/');
      var match = true;

      node_parts.forEach(function (node_part, i) {

        if (node_part !== current_parts[i]) {
          match = false;
        }

      });

      if (match) {
        result.push(node);
      }

    });

    result.should.eql([
      '/products',
      '/products/foobar-super',
    ]);

  });

});
```

Comment: If this is what you ended up using it would be great if you could explain your code and accept your answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you can't accept your own answer within two days of the question.